# How to give somebody access to only some MySQL tables when I cannot create a new MySQL user?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, administration

I am searching for the best solution of the following:

1. I need to give somebody access to one (out of many) specific database on my MySQL server through PhpMyAdmin or a similar tool.
2. I am not allowed to create a new MySQL user account.
3. Therefore I am thinking of creating a cover-up username and password (the credentials might be stored in some table or even directly in PHP somewhere around PMA), with which my somebody would log in to PMA.
4. PMA would use a securely stored real username and password to connect to my MySQL server. But my somebody would never see the actual database username and password. He would only see and be able to edit tables within the one specified database on my server.

Is this somehow achievable? Thank you!

Comment: Is there already a user account that has the limited access that you need? If not, how would step 4 solve the problem? He'll have access to all the tables that the stored username can access.

Comment: And if there is such an account, you can just give him that username and password.

Comment: [dba.se] would probably be a better place for this question.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar - This isn't code related. It's too broad for this area of the network.

Comment: Barmar: No there is no such user. There is only one MySQL username with access to everything and I need my new user to see only one of many databases on the MySQL server. I have and will have no right to create any new MySQL username.

Answer (score 1):

PMA has a configuration for this.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db']
```

Read about it in the documentation: https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html

But this does *not* restrict the privileges of the user. It only makes the user interface show a limited subset of databases to the user. If they know the name of some other databases (or can query them from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA), they can still access those databases.

If you want to enforce privileges to only a few databases, you'll have to create a distinct MySQL user and limit their privileges with [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html).

---

Re your comments:

It sounds like you need to store the MySQL credentials in your PMA config file (and set `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` to 'config'). Then you can use Apache HTTP authentication to restrict access to your PMA site (or directory), and you can create multiple user credentials at the Apache level.

Comment: Thank you, this might actually be enough for what I need to achieve. I will test it and write the result here. :)

Comment: No, I realized that actually it won't be sufficient. I cannot give my new user the real username and password to MySQL. I would need to create something like a separate username and password through which my new user would log in to phpMyAdmin. And phpMyAdmin itself would then use the "real" MySQL username and password to connect to the MySQL server, but it would only show my user one specified database out of many that are there on the server.

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is not designed to work like this; it uses the MySQL authentication structure without imposing any additional login restrictions.

One part of your requirements (not sharing the actual username and password) might be solved by using the config or [signon authentication method](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#example-for-signon-authentication), but that still doesn't impose any additional restrictions on the user once they log in so they'd have the same access that your user account has.

Unfortunately for you, if you aren't able to create another user account it's going to be difficult to share the account without giving them the same level of access.